# Specifying rules for cellular automata in Mathematica

Tags: cellular-automata

The function:

```
CellularAutomaton[73, {{1}, 0}, 4]
```

implements rule 73 for 4 steps with the given initial conditions. How to input this rule, If instead it is to be inputed as it is defined:

[image]

Comment: A rule cannot be inputted as  graphics. If I correctly understand your question, one may form `Table[RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[j]], {j, 0, 255}]` and then find the number of the given as a picture rule  by `EventHandler`. This is a job for professionals and I am not of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I pretend I do not know the rule and we only have an image to go on, I can brute force search the `RulePlot`'s for the closest matching image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHRgv.png"];
ruleimgs = Image[RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[#], Background -> Black]] & /@ Range[255];
Nearest[ruleimgs -> "Index", img, 1] // First
(* result: 73 *)
```

... so the rule is: `RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[73], Background -> Black]`